# Removing first 3 characters of file names in linux

Tags: linux, terminal, sh

I need a sh script to do remove the first 3 characters of file names, for example:

```
"AB file 1.pdf"
"BC file 2.pdf"
"DB file 3.pdf"
"AD file 4.pdf"
...
```

to:

```
"file 1.pdf"
"file 2.pdf"
"file 3.pdf"
"file 4.pdf"
...
```

I think the script will be like:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in *.pdf; do
   newName= ????
   mv $i $newName
done
```

Comment: I do not know how to do that in sh.  In bash (which I realize is off topic), you can used `newName=${i:3}`.  You'll want to do `mv "$i" "$newName"` to prevent spaces from doing bad things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `cut` command:

```
newName=$(echo "$i" | cut -c4-)
```

In `bash` you can use a [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) extension:

```
newName=${i:3}
```

Also, don't forget to quote your variables:

```
mv "$i" "$newName"
```

Otherwise it will think you're trying to move the files named `AB`, `file`, and `1.pdf` to a directory named `1.pdf`.

You could also install the `rename` command if you don't already have it:

```
rename 's/^...//' *.pdf
```