# remove timestamp into file name with bash?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, sh

I'm looking for a way to change the name of my file by giving it a timestamp. This is how it happens:

```
2018-07-20_15:30:27_m_group_types.csv
```

and here is how I wish it to be:

```
m_group_types.csv
```

I really do not see how ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
echo "2018-07-20_15:30:27_m_group_types.csv" | sed -E 's/.*[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+_//'
```

With `awk`:

```
echo "2018-07-20_15:30:27_m_group_types.csv" | awk 'match($0,/.*[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+_/){print substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}'
```

Comment: If you need increment your solution (for many files) you could use something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47316038/removing-first-3-characters-of-file-names-in-linux

Comment: @Paul, cheers and happy learning(along with happy Friday :) )

Answer (score 2):

You can try `cut`

`echo "2018-07-20_15:30:27_m_group_types.csv" | cut -d "_" -f3-`

Output:

`m_group_types.csv`

---

**Explanation:**

`-d`: For *delimiter*, in this case let's choose `"_"`.

`-f`: Choosing the *field* for cutting, in this case the delimiter `"_"` *splits* the string `2018-07-20_15:30:27_m_group_types.csv` to `5` fields:

Field 1: `2018-07-20`

Field 2: `15:30:27`

Field 3: `m`

Field 4: `group`

Field 5: `types.csv`

So using `-f3-` we choosing to cut from `Field 3` and further.

Answer (score 1):

you could also try

```
mv $(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S_)m_group_types.csv m_group_types.csv
```

or

```
mv $(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S_ -d "DATE_HERE_IF_NOT_TODAY")m_group_types.csv m_group_types.csv
```

Comment: This is like typing the `mv` command completely, there is no single form of speed up here. The first command needs to be executed exactly at the time the filename contains, the second command you actually need the time in the variable "DATE_HERE_IF_NOT_TODAY", then you can just skip the `date` command completely.

Answer (score 0):

Using shell substitution, you can do the following:

```
$ filename="2018-07-20_15:30:27_m_group_types.csv"
$ mv "$filename" "${filename#*_*_}"
```

If you have a lot of files of this form, you might consider the use of ZSH and use the `zmv` command:

```
$ zmv -n '[^_]##_[^_]##_(*csv)' '$1'
```

Remove the `-n` to actually do it, (`-n` is a dryrun)